# Remove the value in list based on condition using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array in which the value contains birthday date I need to perform logic in which I need to compare the first value with other if the date range is lesser than 30 remove the second, again compare the first with third if it's greater than 30 keep the first and third and compare the third with fourth if less remove or add and continue

```
arr = ['1/1/2018','14/1/2018','7/2/2018','10/2/2018','14/5/2018']

# ** output here ** 

arr = ['1/1/2018','7/2/2018','14/5/2018']
```

Comment: your code is not valid Python...could you please fix it?  also, your title is about dictionaries...

Comment: @James i think now the question is bit clear

Comment: People can help better if you include also the code you have tried so far. Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines will help us **and you** greatly

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to suggest:

1. Bite the bullet and learn a bit about Datetime and Timedelta.  Plenty of tutorials out there
2. convert everything in your list to a Datetime.  This will help when you have rollovers to consider (5/12/2018, 4/1/2019) and months that have more or less than 30 days
3. ensure your list is sorted
4. make a new list to hold the result.  (do not modify the one while you are looping through it)
5. set up a `while` loop to take the first date, add it to the output, and keep skipping forward in the source list while the next one is less than the date + timedelta.
6. repeat till end of source list.